# Angular sort array as another array

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, lodash

I have one array like below

```
 [
   {
      "key":"Human Resources",
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"1HwahYXr5hs3IDTn7RtC",
            "element":{
               "id":"1HwahYXr5hs3IDTn7RtC",
               "ca":"1x"

            },
            "groupBy":"Human Resources_Human Resources"
         },
         {
            "id":"I7kCoWl7JLCWvgSdZm6p",
            "element":{
               "id":"I7kCoWl7JLCWvgSdZm6p",
               "ca":"2x"

            },
            "groupBy":"Human Resources"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "key":"Marketing",
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"Ltgk4vvKNILwYry1thXL",
            "element":{
               "id":"Ltgk4vvKNILwYry1thXL",
               "ca":"5x"
            },
            "groupBy":"Marketing_Marketing"
         },
         {
            "id":"aA43supw5IYmVLkniC8c",
            "element":{
               "id":"aA43supw5IYmVLkniC8c",
               "ca":"6x"
            },
            "groupBy":"Marketing"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "key":"Sales",
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"WwYl7FelUSVo8i5eMYMk",
            "element":{
               "id":"WwYl7FelUSVo8i5eMYMk",
               "ca":"8x"
            },
            "groupBy":"Sales"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have another array which store ranking of key of above array like below

```
[
{
"id":1,
"name":"Marketing",
"rank":2
},
{
"id":1,
"name":"Human Resources",
"rank":1
}
]
```

I need to sort the first array depending on key rank in second array, If any key is not in second it will be at top..

Please advice is there any inbuit function which can do this like any function in lodash..

Thanks

Comment: please add a result and what you have tried.

Comment: Is the rank unique and consecutive?

Comment: Yes it will be unique

Answer (score 0):

You could take the rank or `-Infinity` for not given ranks for sorting to top.

```js
var array = [{ key: "Human Resources" }, { key: "Marketing" }, { key: "Sales" }],
    ranking = [{ id: 1, name: "Marketing", rank: 2 }, { id: 1, name: "Human Resources", rank: 1 }],
    order = ranking.reduce((o, { name, rank }) => (o[name] = rank, o), Object.create(null));

array.sort(({ key: a }, { key: b }) => (order[a] || -Infinity) - (order[b] || -Infinity));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can forEach the ranquing, filter the data and add property range, then sort the data

```
ranking.forEach(x=>{
  data.filter(d=>d.key==d.name).forEach(df=>{
       df.rank=x.rank; //Add a new property
     }
  })

ranking.sort((a,b)=>(a.rank || 0)-(b.rank || 0));
```

I supouse ranking is the array width the ranking and dat athe array width the data

Comment: is it not possible without loop, atlease not running two loops

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
arr.sort((a,b) => {
  rank1 = rank.find(e => e.name ===a.key);
  rank2 = rank.find(e => e.name ===b.key);
  if (!rank1 || !rank2) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (rank1.rank < rank2.rank) {
    return -1;
 } else {
   return 1;
}
})
```